# Sass::SyntaxError when import custom css and javascript assets in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I got `Sass::SyntaxError:` after running `rake assets:precompile  RAILS_ENV=production  --trace`

Everything works find under `development mode` (without running the precompile)

I add two assets folder used by the two layouts, in  `application.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/themes"

    themes
├── ace-admin-theme
│   ├── avatars
│   ├── css
│   ├── font
│   ├── images
│   ├── img
│   └── js
└── lenord-single-page-theme
    ├── css
    ├── fonts
    ├── img
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    └── rs-assets
```

`rake assets:precompile  RAILS_ENV=production  --trace`

The I got the error message

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...{width:100% \0/": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";height:30px \0..."
  (in /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/Dropbox/Rails/dqa_dev_server/vendor/themes/ace-admin-theme/css/application.css)
(sass):18
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/lexer.rb:206:in `expected!'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:478:in `assert_expr'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:217:in `times_div_or_mod'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:209:in `plus_or_minus'
/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:209:in `relational'
```

in the application.css

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*/
```

---

I use the `ack-grep` and found `{width:100%` in the `colorbox.css`

https://gist.github.com/poc7667/0524dccf620842365f6c

on the line `14`

```
9-#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
10-#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
11-#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
12-#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
13-.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
14:.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}
15-#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;}
16-
17-/*
18-    User Style:
19-    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of Colorbox.  They are
```

Comment: Can you post your error for us please sir?

Comment: Hi I uploaded the error

Comment: Thanks Poc! Let me have a look

Comment: @poc you dont need to specify the assets path if they fall under the standard path(app/assets, lib/assets, vendor/assets)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - looks like you have a syntax error, rather than a directory / path error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...{width:100% \0/"
```

The reason for this, I suspect, is that you *may* be using some of the Asian alphabets, causing character problems, although just a guess?

---

**Fix**

In this file: `vendor/themes/ace-admin-theme/css/application.css`

Can you find the place where you define `{width: 100% ...` & paste in your Q? It looks like a syntax error which we can resolve by changing it

--

**Update**

In reference to your new Github gist, your CSS syntax looks good - I would imagine the issue is caused by non-ASCII characters. Can you try:

```
.cboxIframe {width: 100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}
```